# Windows Remote Desktop Connection and Workspaces Functionality

Tags: keyboard, wine, remote-desktop, rdp, azure

I'm trying to access a remote Windows desktop hosted on Azure from my local Ubuntu 18.04 PC.

There is a link to do this directly from within my browser which works fairly well, however some applications (eg vcxsrv) on the host desktop do not respond to keyboard input, making them useless.

Instead, if I download the latest Windows Remote Desktop Client for Windows or Mac - I can use this to access Azure Workspaces rather than direct use of rdp protocol.  When I do this the keyboard capture problems go away - so they are specific to the browser version (tested on Firefox and Chromium).

Microsoft refer to this in the below doc as "Subscribe to a Workspace":
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/connect-windows-7-10

I've tried running the Windows RDC in latest stable/devel versions of Wine but, whilst install is OK it fails at runtime with error below.

Other Native Linux RDC do not seem to support the Workspaces connections offered by the latest MS Client?

My question is - has anyone found a way of making this work either:

- Success using Wine
- Success using native Linux app
- Success with different browser
- Success by tweaking/fixing keyboard capture in browser

Wine issue:

```
      Unhandled Exception:
  System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException:
  Channel Microsoft Remote Desktop     WPF Client foouser:
  SingeInstanceIPCChannel is not securable while ensureSecurity is specified as trueat System.Runtime.
  Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.RegisterChannel 
  (System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.IChannel chnl, System.Boolean 
  ensureSecurity) [0x0002a] in <7713cb95b33244ed9608bf0b23fbdce9>:0
```

Comment: Windows RDC does not work in Wine.  I don't see a native Linux app that supports Workspaces (because it's a proprietary Microsoft thing and not just the RDP proto).  You might need to run a small Windows VM to use the Microsoft client within a Windows environment, if you don't get an answer)

Answer (score 0):

I use Remmina all the time and it works very well

```
sudo apt install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp
```

Comment: The `remmina` app is the correct answer and usually comes built-in with Ubuntu Desktop. It allows an easy remote connection using RDP, VNC and SSH.

Comment: There are several RDP clients in Linux, but I think there are only beta versions for AVD (Azure Virtual Desktop) in case you need to "suscribe" to a workspace.